# I need a custom Login Registeration in WordPress can somebody guide me?

Tags: user-registration

I want to customize the registeration and login in my WordPress site add a few fields and remove some. Can somebody guide me if i should write my own plugin if that is the case what steps i should follow. IF i can use some already written plugin please direct me to that?

Answer (score 1):

the developer license of Gravity Forms has a user registration add-on.

Comment: And it's awesome.